# Google Chrome Custom.css webkit-scrollbar no longer works

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, scrollbar

Chrome recently updated to(Version 33.0.1750.117 m) and i was using a custom scroll bar because i hate that white one.  This update came out and this code is not effecting this browser anymore.

`::-webkit-scrollbar {height: 12px!important;width: 12px!important;background: -webkit-linear-gradient(40deg , #000000 , #1e1e1e , #000000 100%)!important;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {background-color: #840000!important;border-radius: 16px!important;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {background: #0000!important;}`

Anyone have a clue what they did and most importantly how to get this working again. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My chrome browser verion is 34.0.1847.116 m.
The following styles are still working in my chrome:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0);
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar:hover {
    width: 7px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #FAE5F6;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover,
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active  {
    background: #fabae1;
}
```

Check once....If still doesn't work, try after upgrading your chrome...

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 9):

Here's a workaround to get custom CSS back in Google Chrome:

1. Create a folder and call it, say `CustomCss`
2. In the folder, create a file called `manifest.json` with the following content:

   ```
   {
       "name": "My Style Sheet",
       "content_scripts": [
           {
             "matches": ["*://*/*"],
             "css": ["Custom.css"]
           }
       ],
       "version": "1.0.0",
       "description": "User StyleSheet replacement",
       "manifest_version": 2
   }
   ```
3. In the folder, copy your `Custom.css` file from the *User StyleSheets* folder.
4. Go to chrome://extensions
5. Make sure *Developer mode* is checked.
6. Click [Load unpacked extension...]
7. Browse to the folder created in step 1 and click [OK].
8. Breathe sigh of relief.

Source: [Comment #4 on Chromium Issue 340072](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=340072#c4)

Answer (score 0):

The whole User Stylesheet (`Custom.css`) is broken. I've reported an issue (from the About page).

Using an extension like Stylish is not a better option because extensions take up RAM and since there are so many useful ones you will have a few already (Google Dictionary, AdBlock and something to fix the Download shelf come to mind). Userscripts are also a poor choice because no global styles. I use Custom.css to style image URLs and internal urls like `chrome://settings`, which I don't believe I could do with userscripts.

I appologize I don't have a fix but I can't comment.

Comment: I do styling with userstyles and i noticed yesterday when they released the update it affected my extensions as well and i needed to repatch them.  

I hope they read your report because the Custom.css is nice to use. To me the scroll bar is disgusting to see on dark styled sites.